# cUrl Request with api_key, Convert to PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to cUrl requests and am having the toughest time converting this cUrl command to PHP.
Here's the command:

```
curl --request GET https://api.myseotool.com/v2/campaigns \
  -u {api_key}: \
```

And here's what I have so far (not working):

```
$host = 'https://api.myseotool.com/v2/campaigns';
$process = curl_init($host);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/json']);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $apiKey); //already saved to this variable
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($process, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$response = curl_exec($process);
```

This is returning an error (from the api):

> {"error_code":"invalid_api_key","error_msg":" The supplied API key is
>   invalid."}

Comment: Did you try `$apiKey.':'` (as in the original request) as well?

Comment: kingkero: I did with no luck.

Comment: You have to set `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER` option to `false` (or `0`) unless you're going to provide `CURLOPT_CAINFO` option